# How can I turn on ragdoll when a CharacterBody3D enters an Area3D?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have a car scene and a zombie CharacterBody3D scene and I am trying make it so that when the car hits the zombie, the zombie starts physical bones simulation (and also deals damage based on impact, but that is the next step).

I have tried to implement this using an Area3D that surrounds the car and emitting a signal when the zombie CharacterBody3D enters the area to then turn on physical bones simulation, but I have something not setup correctly and not sure what it is.

Here is my script that is attached to the car's Area3D
[image]

Here is my script that is attached to the zombie
[image]

Here is how the area3D is setup on the car
[image]
Here is how the characterbody3d is setup on the zombie
[image]
Notice how the print is not printing when the characterbody3d enters the area3d...
[image]
I am thinking I either have the signal hooked up incorrectly or am missing some logic so that the signal isn't being emitted when the CharacterBody3D enters the area. Or I could be doing everything wrong here hah! Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal is likely connected correctly. When a signal is connected from the editor, you should see the green icon here:

[image]

Unless you have connected the wrong signal, which is unlikely, that should be OK.

---

Now, check the `collision_mask` of the `Area3D` has overlap with the `collision_layer` of the `CharacterBody3D`, also make sure the `Area3D` has `monitoring` enabled.

---

You can also add a `print` on the connected function:

```
func _on_body_entered(body):
    print(body)
    if body is CharacterBody3D:
        body._on_body_entered()
```

That way you would know if this method is being called, and being called with the correct object.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I have some ragdoll issues now to solve but one step closer. Cheers!